# Implementing JWT Authentication in Blazor Server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm working on implementing JWT authentication in my Blazor Server, and I'm seeking a proper way to **managing authentication state** and tokens securely on the server. Most of the samples and answers are using **WebAssembly** and for the server, they used built-in Identity.
I have an API that supports JWT authentication. Upon successful authentication, the API generates a JWT token, which I need to handle securely in my Blazor Server. I want to use identity tags like

```
@attribute [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Authorize]
```

in my app. How can I implement an authentication service that lets me use tags and built-in feature?

Comment: You should be able to adapt the Web Assembly examples.  You can configure `HttpClient` on the server to make the API calls to get the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Add jwt bearer authentication to blazor server is same as adding to webapi project. You need to know some token validation information (pasting token to this https://jwt.io/) and then use them to configure `AddAuthentication` service in program.cs

```
...
 builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
                {
                    opt.Audience = "";
                    opt.Authority = "";
                });
...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```